# Can't SendCodeRequestAsync TLSharp Telegram

Tags: c#, telegram

I can't SendCodeRequestAsync() when i using TLsharp

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new TelegramClient(974478, "51bdb94bc9fe51f5ad606bf1b7053521");
    await client.ConnectAsync();

    var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("+6281277xxxx");
    var code = "<code_from_telegram>"; // you can change code in debugger

    var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync("<user_number>", hash, code);
}
```

I get an error in the line

```
var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync("+6281277xxxx");
```

The error is:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Seems like a network issue, no?

Comment: No, i open youtube it's fine